# Strange lines in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, openlayers

In the last weeks I developed a map of the Antarctic continent with an azimuthal projection using ArcGIS maps. To also show the surrounding areas there is a normal map wrapped around. [The solution for this is from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978836/openlayers-map-doesnt-render-with-a-non-standard-epsg-code/)

After successfully implementing all the desired functions in Firefox, I checked the result in Chrome too and got some strange results

[image: map in Chrome]

In firefox everything looks fine:

[image: map in Firefox]

Does anybody what that even is and how to fix it?

Comment: those lines don't appear in Chrome on that answer where your code is from - so, you must've done something to that code which produces these artefacts - either that or your Chrome is different to my Chrome - do you see those artefacts in that answer?

Comment: No, I actually don't see these artefacts in the code snippets. I opened the project in Chrome for the first time at a very progressed state of the project, so I have bit of trouble spotting where this comes from.